# Combining assemblies with visual studio using ILMerge or something else

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, msbuild, ilmerge

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

I have 3 C# class library projects, A, B & C.

A references B

B referencess C

When I compile and build project "A" in visual studio, I see A.dll, B.dll and C.dll in the bin folder of project "A".

Now I planned to merge B.dll and C.dll inside A.dll.

I tried using below ILMerge command but the contents of A.dll are lost.

```
ilmerge /out:A.dll A.dll B.dll C.dll  /targetplatform:v4
```

Any idea how can this be achived?
I wan't B and C merged in A without loosing A's content.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to change out argument to D.dll.

Comment: @Lexi: Yeah, I know that but I don't want a new assembly.

Comment: then probably first rename A to D and then merge B, C, D to A.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a multi-step process as follows by running three commands:

**1.** create temp assembly from 3 input assemblies.

**2.** delete original libraryA.dll assembly.

**3.** rename temp assembly to libraryA.dll.

Example:

3 commands executed on a single line by using **"&"** separator.

```
C:\<somepath>\Debug>"C:\<somepath>"\ILMerge.exe /out:temp.dll libraryA.dll libraryB.dll libraryC.dll  /targetplatform:v4 & del /F /Q libraryA.dll & ren temp.dll libraryA.dll
```

Output (viewed in ILSpy for convenience):

[image: ILSpy showing code from multiple sources merged into single assembly]

> **IMPORTANT:** You should consider following this process only with Release builds.
> If done against debug builds with .pdb files the rename performed in the 3rd step of the example will void the ability to debug the assemblies. related info on [SO: here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064741/how-do-i-debug-into-an-ilmerged-assembly)
>
> **NOTE:** If your intention is to maintain the assembly version of the original libraryA.dll assembly in the process you'll need to get more
> creative i.e. source the assembly version and subsequently passing the version to the **/ver:version** argument of ILMerge.exe.
> If considering running ILMerge as a postbuild event the following links related to getting the version are applicable.
>
> [SO: getting version in postbuild event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243593/determine-assembly-version-during-a-post-build-event)
>
> [SO: getting version in commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037008/assembly-version-from-command-line)
>
> Invoking ILMerge as a postbuild is discussed [SO: here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556048/how-to-integrate-ilmerge-into-visual-studio-build-process-to-merge-assemblies?rq=1)

Also note: A question similar to yours was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765615/ilmerge-keep-assembly-name) without an example based answer.